# Flutter xcode build is done and stuck with Waiting for observatory port to be available... while it is perfectly working with android emulator

Tags: flutter

My Flutter project is working perfectly fine on android emulator but when I run the ios, it stuck after xcode build done and it shows no error at all. But when opens the app which is installed on simulator, it doesn't work (it closes all of a sudden without showing any error)

Comment: How do you expect us to guess?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. the issue was because of the compatibility of iOS deployment target. My Simulator iOS version was 13.4 but ios deployment target was selected as iOS 14.0, so when I decreased the iOS deployment target less than to iOS 13.4, it worked :)
You can do this by opening your flutter project in Xcode and then select the target Runner then go to the tab Build Settings -> iOS deployment target.